# How to get and post cookies through loopj network library in android?

Tags: android, cookies, loopj

I have  an app which requires to save and send cookies back to server but i don't know how to send and get cookies.
Any good soul please help.
**I can even accept answers of volley library to get and post cookies.**

Answer (score 1):

First, create an instance of AsyncHttpClient:

```
AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
```

Now set this client’s cookie store to be a new instance of PersistentCookieStore, constructed with an activity or application context (usually this will suffice):

```
PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
myClient.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
```

Any cookies received from servers will now be stored in the persistent cookie store.

To add your own cookies to the store, simply construct a new cookie and call addCookie:

```
BasicClientCookie newCookie = new BasicClientCookie("cookiesare", "awesome");
newCookie.setVersion(1);
newCookie.setDomain("mydomain.com");
newCookie.setPath("/");
myCookieStore.addCookie(newCookie);
```

See the [PersistentCookieStore Javadoc](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/PersistentCookieStore.html) for more information.

Comment: cookies are sent from server side at first and we have to store it for future requests.?

Comment: how to get cookies from response ?

Comment: Check this: https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/PersistentCookieStore.html#getCookies--